# How to make batch file start at a specific time every day?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

How do I write a batch file that starts at 2 AM every day?

For example, remove and make a folder:

```
:START
rmdir /s /q "D:\share"
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 100 
mkdir "D:\share"
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 100
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create a regular batch file and then create a scheduled task.

This page provides simple step-by-step instructions: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000785.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
schtasks /create /sc daily /TN AName /tr "Path-to-your-batch-file" /st 02:00 /f
```