# daily auto open another powerpoint

Tags: java, autostart

I need to take care of a TV, which is supposed to have a daily changing presentation (Meetings, schedules, etc.).
Now, instead of opening daily a slideshow, i am looking for a way to create a program (Java) or something in Windows that does that for me. Something like:

every morning at 6 a.m. check if slideshow named "ddmmyyyy" is available, if so, open that slideshow

if not, open "master"

my abilities in Java are not the best, so i am open for other suggestions...

Thanks

Comment: I am not a Windows user, but take a look at **Windows Script Host**. Writing a fully-blown application for that seems unsuited for the task.

Comment: This is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe you have a windows computer behind that TV?.

Create a batch-script opening your powerpoint, schedule it via windows. Et voila, your done.

of course you could write a program for that, but I believe that is not reqruired.

Codes here:
https://superuser.com/questions/727724/close-programs-from-the-command-line-windows ( close powerpoint if still running )

[How to make batch file start at a specific time every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171624/how-to-make-batch-file-start-at-a-specific-time-every-day/20171658) ( opening powerpoint )

Comment: Thanks! That does it pretty well.